# CSS border collapse not applying to top and left border

Tags: html, css

This is a test template~
In orde to debug, I have changed the border colour of div (parent of the table) to red. 
As it is shown, you can clearly see there are BLACK border on the top and the left. 
I can't fix it. 
Please help.

html:

```
<div class="roundcorner">
<table border="1 solid">
    <tr>
        <th>Out of 100 points how would you score Governemnt performance for each section.</th>
        <th>Most like to see increased</th>
        <th>Most willing to see decreased</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="p2">
                <input type="text" name="name" />
            </td>
            <td id="i1">lakdksakdmksa</td>
            <td id="d1">
                <input type="radio" name="sex" />Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="p2">
                <input type="text" name="name" />
            </td>
            <td id="i2">dsfwsedfwefwe</td>
            <td id="d2">
                <input type="radio" name="sex" />No</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>
```

css:

```
.roundcorner {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}
.roundcorner table {
   // border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
   border: 1px solid grey;
    overflow: hidden
}
th {
    background-color: #EEE;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    text-align: centre;
    //border: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr:hover {
    background: #fafafa;
    // font-weight:bold;
}
input[type=radio] {
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-right: 45%;
}
input[type=text] {
    width:20%;
    height:20px;
    margin-left:40%;
    margin-right:40%;
    border-radius:3px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
td:first-child {
    width: 25%;
    height:60px;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 25%;
    height:60px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/707ha2vq/3/)

Comment: Why do you have a `border="1 solid"` on your table? It's not even a valid value for the `border` attribute.

Comment: very neat eye. Thank you!

Comment: Apparently, the top border and the left border is still thicker than the others. do you know why?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting your posts.

Comment: r u looing like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/707ha2vq/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for this:

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/707ha2vq/5/

You are having elements containing one another and both with borders, so you get double borders. In a table, you normally give `td` elements a border and `border-collapse: collapse;` so borders that are together collapse in two elements. But you are having cell's border and row's border so it won't collapse, there is where you see double or triple borders.

```
.roundcorner {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}
.roundcorner table {
   // border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}
th {
    background-color: #EEE;
    padding: 10px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
td {
    text-align: centre;
    //border: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr:hover {
    background: #fafafa;
    // font-weight:bold;
}
input[type=radio] {
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-right: 45%;
}
input[type=text] {
    width:20%;
    height:20px;
    margin-left:40%;
    margin-right:40%;
    border-radius:3px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
td:first-child {
    width: 25%;
    height:60px;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 25%;
    height:60px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! THIS is what I want:[JSFiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/707ha2vq/9/

Comment: But I got what you mean, so I had to set "border-bottom: 0px;" to some elements to get rid of thicker border. Just wonder is this the best solution?

Comment: Oh man sorry, I thought you wanted to keep the lower part without borders. I would have add it if you asked for it.

Comment: @MatildaYiPan as I said, the most common solution is to use borders just in cells, just in your td element and border-collapse: collapse and you will get exactly the same border you showed in your jsfiddle. Don't add borders to the container or to rows, just cells and it will to the job

Answer (score 0):

I think the those extra borders are of Table borders. Try to replace your css mentioned above with the following, What I did is removed border for table and given required borders for individual header

```
    .roundcorner {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden
    }
    .roundcorner table {
       // border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        border-spacing: 0;
       //border: 1px solid grey;
        overflow: hidden
    }
    th:first-child {
        background-color: #EEE;
        padding: 10px;
        border-right: 1px solid grey;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
       border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th:nth-child(2) {
        background-color: #EEE;
        padding: 10px;
        border-right: 1px solid grey;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
       border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th:nth-child(3) {
        background-color: #EEE;
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
       border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td {
        text-align: centre;
        //border: 1px solid grey;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    tr:hover {
        background: #fafafa;
        // font-weight:bold;
    }
    input[type=radio] {
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-left: 45%;
        margin-right: 45%;
    }
    input[type=text] {
        width:20%;
        height:20px;
        margin-left:40%;
        margin-right:40%;
        border-radius:3px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }
    td:first-child {
        width: 25%;
        height:60px;
    }
    td:nth-child(2) {
        width: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    td:nth-child(3) {
        width: 25%;
        height:60px;
    }
```